# How to create a join() function

Tags: javascript, join, methods

```
function join(a,b){
    var conc ="";
    if(!a){
         conc = "   ";
    }else if(!b){
         for(var i=0; i < a.length;i++){
              conc+=a[i]+"  ";
         }       
    }else{
         for(var i=0; i < a.length;i++){
             conc+=a[i]+b;
         } 
    }
    conc=conc.substring(0,conc.length-2)
    return conc;  
}
```

I have to create a function that does exactly what `Array.join()` method  does , obviously with out using `join()`. I came up with this code so far.
The default should be an empty string.
I know it's wrong but I dont know what to do next.

Comment: If you already know which parts are wrong, why don't you tell us? And why not use some kind of TDD approach to come to the final solution?

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the implementation I would use.  We can avoid most the lengthy logic you had for avoiding non truthy `a` or `b`.

```js
function join(a, b) {
    b = !b ? "," : b;   // default a non truthy separator to comma
    if (!a) return "";
    
    var output = "";
    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        output += i > 0 ? b : "";   // do not add separator after last element
        output += a[i];
    }

    return output;
}

var a = ['Fire', 'Wind', 'Rain'];
console.log(join(a, ":"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not a developer yet, I am learning every day.